# Email on failure/retry with airflow in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, smtp, airflow

I am trying to run the puckel airflow docker container using the LocalExecutor.yml file found here:

https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

I am not able to get airflow to send me emails on failure or retry.

I've tried the following:

1. Editing the config file with the smtp host name

```
[smtp]
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = smtp@mycompany.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
# Uncomment and set the user/pass settings if you want to use SMTP AUTH
# smtp_user = airflow
# smtp_password = airflow
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from = myname@mycompany.com
```

2. Editing environment variables in the entrypoint.sh script included in the repo:

```
: "${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST:="smtp-host"}"
: "${AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT:="25"}"
# Defaults and back-compat
: "${AIRFLOW_HOME:="/usr/local/airflow"}"
: "${AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY:=${FERNET_KEY:=$(python -c "from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; FERNET_KEY = Fernet.generate_key().decode(); print(FERNET_KEY)")}}"
: "${AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR:=${EXECUTOR:-Sequential}Executor}"



export \
  AIRFLOW_HOME \
  AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL \
  AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND \
  AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR \
  AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY \
  AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES \
  AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN \
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST \
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT \

if [ "$AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST" != "smtp-host" ]; then
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST="smtp-host"
  AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT=25
fi
```

I currently have a dag running that intentionally fails, but I am never alerted for retries or failures.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do steps 1 and 2. Specify the environment variable in the docker-compose.yml.
Also, make sure that you have enabled email sending on failure in the Operator,
like in here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aawgit/0753b3ef1d715257e442ceafbc8583d3/raw/fa45caa9150e08654d476c2d619ab50615942b46/email-notification-on-task-failure.py

Answer (score 0):

Set the following variables to make mail function work.
It depends on the config of the SMTP mail server.
User name and password should be set correctly.

- If use docker-compose, setting the following variable in docker-compose.yml will auto update the airflow variables:

```
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST=smtp_host
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT=25_?_the_smtp_port_used_smtp_host
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER=mail_user_name_of_your_app
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD=mail_user_password_of_your_app
- AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM=mail_user_name_of_your_app@mail.server.name
```

- Similarly, if bring up docker manually, setting the following variables as environment variables:

```
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST=smtp_host
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT=25_?_the_smtp_port_used_smtp_host
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER=mail_user_name_of_your_app
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD=mail_user_password_of_your_app
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM=mail_user_name_of_your_app@mail.server.name

export AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM

# Then bring up docker:
docker run your_docker...
```